# Is it possible to 'hide' or disable the turtle screen and just capture the final graphic?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How necessary is viewing the canvas window that a Turtle object draws on? Can it be hidden or disable and just the final graphics captured?

I have a python script that uses the `turtle` library and am wondering is it crucial for the canvas window, where one can view the actual drawing being created, to be open during the script's runtime? Is it possible to not even load the visual portion of the canvas and simply capture the data at the end? (which btw I create a .ps file with and use `PIL` to convert it to a .jpg).

Would this perhaps make the overall script run faster as I am planning on bumping up my iteration count significantly and it is already fairly slow as is (which could of course be the nature of the library and I have to just deal with it)?

Having searched Google, the only issues I could find with terms like, "hide turtle canvas" or "disable canvas window" just netted me issues unrelated to my question. I have also searched through the `turtle` library documentation and no function or methods seemed to do the job, but of course I could have missed it.

I'm not familiar with the root package `tkinter` so if there is something on that end that I could mess with I can look into that as a solution. But I wouldn't know where to begin as I don't fully comprehend the relationship between `tkinter` and `turtle`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (MRE) of some `turtle`-based graphics you would like to have this done to. Have you tried using PIL to convert the .ps file into another format? From what I understand that requires Ghostscript to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using *embedded* turtle, we can create and withdraw the Tk root window immediately and then simply work with a `Canvas`:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import RawTurtle

(root := Tk()).withdraw()

canvas = Canvas(root)
turtle = RawTurtle(canvas)
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.begin_poly()

for _ in range(5):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(360/5)

turtle.end_poly()

print(turtle.get_poly())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
((0.00,0.00), (100.00,0.00), (130.90,-95.11), (50.00,-153.88), (-30.90,-95.11), (0.00,0.00))
>
```

I'm intentionally avoiding the `TurtleScreen` and `ScrolledCanvas` wrapper classes as we don't need any interactive methods.

The same thing could probably be done from *standalone* turtle by digging into the underpinnings via `getcanvas()` and finding the root window to withdraw.

Not perfect, but on my system I don't see any window.  If you see a flash of one, look up the tkinter `overrideredirect(1)` method, calling it just before the `withdraw()` to avoid the flash.

Comment: A few points cdlane. I apologize for not getting back sooner, I haven't been able to work on this project for some time. Thank you for your reply and I have been able to make it work, but one problem I'm having is that albeit yes I don't have a window visible, I do still have one 'open' on my task bar using this method. Also despite my turtle's speed being set to 0 or 'fastest' it is incredibly slow, I mean like 15+ minutes compared to 10 seconds using this method. I'm not sure what the difference is. If I just use t = turtle.Turtle() without your root code then it is incredibly fast